# Stop an int from increasing or decreasing for a certain amount of time

Tags: java, int

I am currently working on a Java game, and I have an int that represents the player's health, which starts at 100, and the health decreases by 5 every time it intersects with an enemy, however, it checks for this 60 times a second, so, it decreases rapidly as for that second, the player is making contact with the enemy, therefore going down by 300 each second that it's touching it. I'm wondering if it's possible to stop an int's value from changing for about 3-5 seconds? I don't know if that is possible, I tried this :

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(4000);
} catch(InterruptedException ie) {
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

And then the int can be added to after that, but that just stops the whole program for 4 seconds, and there is other things going on at that time.

Comment: I think you have to give us some more context here.

Comment: write a setter method and control there.............

Comment: You need to stop focusing on "how to stop an int from decreasing", and instead reconsider how your game loop works. Things like this need to be consolidated into "events" that occur just once. When the player *first* touches an enemy, the "contact" event occurs, and not until the player has stopped touching the enemy (and some time has passes, called "hysteresis"), can that event happen again. It's tricky, but you need to go about it the right way, else your code will quickly become a giant steaming pile.

Answer (score 1):

"*Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution*" - Don't use it if you don't want to stop the whole thread.

You can create a thread that will be responsible of changing the `int` value, then in order to perform a periodic task, you can use [ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). For example:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //...
    }
};

ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable , INITIAL_DELAY, PERIOD, TIMEUNIT);
```

Now you can decide when the Thread will be run and for how long. However, I recommend you to reconsider your design before it'll be too late and your code will be messy.